# Resizing a DockPanel to DockZone height and width

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am trying to resize a dynamic dock panel to the size of the dock zone in which it's contained in javascript(client-side) at runtime. I am using the Dev Express DockZone and DockPanel. My JScript looks like this:

```
function setDockPanelFill() {
    var dockPanel = ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName('dockPanel1');
    var dockZone = document.getElementById('zone1');
    dockPanel.SetHeight = dockZone.offsetHeight;
    dockPanel.SetWidth = dockZone.offsetWidth;
}
```

Any ideas on why this won't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [ASPxDockZone](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxDockingASPxDockZonetopic).[ClientInstanceName](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxDockingASPxDockZone_ClientInstanceNametopic) to e.g. dockZone1.
Set [ASPxDockPanel](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxDockingASPxDockPaneltopic).[PanelUID](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxDockingASPxDockPanel_PanelUIDtopic) to e.g. dockPanel1.
Also, [SetHeight](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesScriptsASPxClientControl_SetHeighttopic) and [SetWidth](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesScriptsASPxClientControl_SetWidthtopic) are methods, not properties.
So your code should look like this:

```js
function setDockPanelFill() {
    var dockPanel = dockZone1.GetPanelByUID('dockPanel1');
    dockPanel.SetHeight(dockZone1.GetHeight());
    dockPanel.SetWidth(dockZone1.GetWidth());
}
```